# Which House Was Gilderoy Lockhart In?

Tags: harry-potter, sorting-hat

. . . And don't automatically say Slytherin just because he was a huge ponce. ;)

Seriously, though, using canon as a guide, what house would Gilderoy Lockhart have been Sorted into? He certainly had ambition, which Slytherin prized. It took a lot of nerve to pull off taking credit for other people's accomplishments for as many years as he did, and nerve and courage are Gryffindor traits. He worked hard at maintaining his façade for years; hard work is a Hufflepuff trait. While the accomplishments he claimed in his books were not his own, he did write a solid number of books (assuming he didn't have a ghost writer) and to effectively write for an audience takes intelligence, the main Ravenclaw trait.

We also know his magic wasn't very good. Perhaps this doesn't mean much, for Neville's magic wasn't strong and he was Sorted to Gryffindor. Anyhow . . .

Keeping this info -- and whatever else you know from canon -- in mind, **which Hogwarts house would Gilderoy Lockhart have been Sorted to?**

Comment: Slytherin. He was a huge ponce.

Comment: Well, since he ended up in the St Mungo's Hospital for Magical Maladies and Injuries, it would be safe to say he was in the nuthouse.

Comment: @dlanod - You're very funny. . . ;)

Comment: He may have fitted Ravenclaw perfectly when he got sorted, but maybe now he fits the description of a Slytherin more.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Lockhart was in **Ravenclaw**.

In *Chamber of Secrets* special edition, on disc 2  of the DVD or on the Ultimate Edition Bluray, there is a special feature called "Lockhart's Classroom." In that feature, we see a photo of Lockhart during his school days in Ravenclaw's Quidditch uniform, as he played Seeker. I realize the movies aren't as canon as other canon, but it seems highly unlikely that they'd make that up without input from JKR.

As to why he was sorted into Ravenclaw, I suspect that much like Harry, it's because he wanted to be. Lockhart, for all his bluff and buffoonery, fancied himself as an intelligent individual. Indeed, faking his way through life like he did, required as much wit and intellect as actually learning the things to be genuinely successful would have, if not more.

We also have to consider that when he was sorted, he may have not developed his cheating side yet. The thing with those who are really academically smart, is that sometimes it doesn't carry over into day to day life. I suspect Lockhart was a good student who never actually had to use magic in reality, never got good at it, and decided to bluff his way through life rather than admit he was unskilled.

Comment: Wait, you're saying that the intellect used for fooling everyone for a selfish reason puts Lockhart in Ravenclaw, but fooling everyone to keep company to a friend in his hard days puts Pettigrew in Gryffindor?

Comment: This is *very* interesting. Quirrell was a Ravenclaw too. The Slytherin welcome letter from Pottermore mentions that the three other houses have turned out their fair share of bad apples, but just don't admit it or talk about it. I find it fascinating thinking of Lockhart in Ravenclaw. Thanks for a great answer :)

Comment: @b_jonas I'm not saying anything :P If you don't like the sorting, tell the Hat. :) I'm just offering an opinion of why the Hat made the choice it made. As to Pettigrew, I would honestly assume he chose Gryffindor. Everyone seems to hastily forget that the Hat considers your choice in the matter.

Comment: +1 and accept -- I finally got a chance to check out the extra features on the *CoS* Ultimate Edition BluRay. Yep, you're right :)

Comment: The hat seems to **consider** your choice, but we only have an example of it considering Harry's thoughts when there was another house that was also suitable.  Harry simply says, "not Slytherin" not, I can't stand Slytherin, please put me in Grffindor instead."  Plus, consider is different from simply letting the student decide.

Comment: @balancedmama -- Here's what Harry says to Albus Severus when Albus Severus is off to his first year at Hogwarts: *won’t it? It doesn’t matter to us, Al. But if it matters to you, you’ll be able to choose Gryffindor over Slytherin. The Sorting Hat takes your choice into account.’* No, this still isn't perfect wording, but it is from canon, and states that a child *can* choose their house placement. I know I don't need to tell you this (parenting mod!) but, you know, even a kid can know what's in his or her heart and express that very earnestly. :)

Comment: Ravenclaws *value* knowledge over all else. You don't **have** to be intelligent to value intelligence and knowledge. Lockhart certainly wanted to be someone who wrote books, gained knowledge and passed it on to others. But his *methods* of acquiring that knowledge (ie stealing/borrowing it from other witches/wizards, and embellishing tales of his own quick-witted thinking) were unconventional. I think it's not unreasonable for Lockhart to be a Ravenclaw.

Answer (score 12):

I'd have to say judging on how he is when Harry meets him he's (probably) a Slytherin.

A Hufflepuff would have have worked hard to get where he has, by honest hard work.

> Where they are **just and loyal**,
> Those patient Hufflepuffs are true,
> And **unafraid of toil**"

Yet he betrays the trio, and shirks any actual work in getting his fame.

A Gryffindor would have more courage to face the actual tasks he had 'faked'.

> Where dwell the **brave at heart**,
> Their daring, **nerve** and **chivalry**
> Set Gryffindors apart

Sure he had some nerve in faking the deeds, but no true chivalry, nor was he brave at heart.

That leaves Ravenclaw and Slytherin. But Ravenclaw says

> If you've a ready mind,
> Where those of **wit and learning**,
> Will always find their kind."

Gilderoy didn't get anywhere by wit nor learning. He didn't research the spell to cure the lycanthropy he mentions in his book. He cheats and connives his way to fame.

So we are left with Slytherin,

> You'll make your real friends,
> Those cunning folk **use any means,
> To achieve their ends**."

I couldn't have put it better myself. In the end he really does use every last means to get the fame and fortune he really wants.

### Edit:

<sub>In response to comments by @MarkBeadle, it really comes down to, would Gilderoy have preferred Slytherin to Ravenclaw or vice versa? I just have to say, it's a very *Slytherin* thing to do, to chose a different house to the one the Hat chooses simply so you can look smart and get ahead in life. That is if young Gilderoy was as slimy and deceitful as his adult self. But as I couldn't find any references to this, or his actual house I'll concede to Gabe Willard's [answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/15626/3804).</sub>

Comment: Really nice answer! Especially the canon references -- thanks for that :)

Comment: okay answer, but it doesn't reflect the fact that the hat takes one's own wishes into account. E.g. you might be sorted into Hufflepuff if you're lazy but *think* you're industrious.

Answer (score 5):

@Pureferret's answer is wrong... but right :)

Lockhart was, indeed, a Ravenclaw, as @Gabe's answer states... BUT...

As of Jan 2014, JKR [posted 3 short audio clips on Pottermore](http://www.theguardian.com/childrens-books-site/2014/jan/25/jk-rowling-harry-potter-audio-exclusive), which revealed that, in the words of Wikia: "The Sorting Hat fought to place him in Slytherin, a House from which he narrowly escaped into Ravenclaw". The exact wording in the first clip was:

> "He was Sorted into Ravenclaw House... though I suspect, I think that people would be unsurprised to hear, that I think he narrowly escaped Slytherin... that he scraped into Ravenclaw." ([src](http://pottermoreanalysis.tumblr.com/post/74644957096/jk-rowling-on-gilderoy-lockharts-house-audio))