# Were all the Hogwarts Professors former Hogwarts students?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts

According to the Harry Potter book series, was being a former Hogwarts student a prerequisite for a Witch or a Wizard to become a Professor at Hogwarts?

Comment: "were" and "was it required" can be quite different in cases like this.

Comment: I don't think it's required.  That would hinder spreading knowledge between different schools of wizardy, and as such, it would be foolish.

Comment: Although Hagrid went to Hogwarts, he didn't even graduate. I like the idea that Hogwarts is an EOE - equal opportunity employer. What kinds of benefits do you think they have? Kidding.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I would say no because Hogwarts is not a requirement for any witch or wizard. Some families homeschool (Mrs. Weasley taught the Weasley kids at home until they went to Hogwarts) and some send their kids to other schools (Lucius Malfoy wanted to send Draco to Durmstrang, but Narcissa objected to Draco being so far away from home).

It was only under Voldemort's reign during *Deathly Hallows* that Hogwarts was compulsory, but then again only for purebloods. Muggleborns were excluded from Hogwarts during that time.

So, again, no -- I don't think Hogwarts teachers have to have attended Hogwarts in order to teach.

**Did not attend:**

- **Firenze**

**Possibly did not attend Hogwarts:**

- Trelawney (Dumbledore did not seem familiar with Trelawney when he recounted his first meeting with her at the Hog's Head)

**Former Hogwarts students who became teachers at Hogwarts:**

- Snape
- McGonagall
- Dumbledore
- Sprout
- Flitwick
- Hagrid
- Neville
- Lupin
- Quirrell
- Lockhart
- Slughorn

**Unknown:**

- Barty Crouch Jr/Moody
- Umbridge
- the Carrows
- Charity Burbage (Muggle Studies)
- Sinistra (Astronomy)
- Vector (Arithmancy)
- Grubbly-Plank (COMC)
- Binns (History of Magic)

If I've forgotten anyone else, leave a comment and I'll edit.

Comment: Only muggle-borns were excluded, wizards only needed to prove one wizarding ancestor.

Comment: @Kevin - Thanks for blowing my cover as a geeky, insufferable Potter know-it-all . . . In reality, I have actually never read the books. :P ;)

Comment: @Slytherincess - "In reality, I have actually never read the books" - Oh! So YOU are the HP editor!

Comment: BTW, you know you can delete 90% of the answer and merely leave Firense :)  I shoulda been an editor :)

Comment: @DVK - The OCD side of me insists upon the full list! And, yes, I am surely the HP editor -- Even as I type this I'm laughing at the plotholes all the way to the bank ;)

Comment: JKR says at http://web.archive.org/web/20110623034500/http://www.jkrowling.com/textonly/en/faq_view.cfm?id=62 that heads of houses were in the same house, so Slughorn has definitely attended Hogwarts.

Comment: Not to challenge you - because I really just want to know - Where does it say lockhart was a student in the Canon?  Does it also confirm which house he was in?  I'm not sure I trust he was a Ravenclaw.

Comment: You can challenge me all you like! It's no problem :) See **Gabe Willard**'s answer to "Which house was Gilderoy Lockhart in?" right [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/15626/3500), where Gabe gives a full explanation regarding Lockhart and Ravenclaw House. :)

Comment: Isn't it known that Umbridge was in Slytherin? Or is that non-canon?

Comment: @Janus: I recall Umbridge was labelled a Slytherin on her Pottermore page. Since the Pottermore update her House is no longer listed on her page, but she certainly did attend Hogwarts: https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/dolores-umbridge